# Travel agent booked ticket when passport has less than 3 months left

Tags: legal, germany, canadian-citizens, disputes

Briefly, my boyfriend's mum booked a ticket for me to Germany through a travel agent. The travel agent requested a scan of my passport photo page (which shows the expiry date). I hold a Canadian passport.

The problem was discovered right before I was boarding the plane, after check in and security and they did not let me on since I had less than 3 months left on my passport by the time I would be departing Germany.

My question is, should the travel agent (a person who personally reviewed the documents when the ticket was booked) or agency be responsible for the cost of rebooking the flight?

Comment: While it would have been good for the travel agent to catch this and warn you, pretty much every travel agent I've seen clearly states that you, the traveler, are responsible for all travel documents and compliance with entry requirements. Unfortunately, I think you're on your own for this one, though it's worth trying to see if the airline is willing to give you a break.

Answer (score 2):

Since you will be held-responsible, the travel agent nor the agency agree to covering the cost of rebooking the flight. Their probable argument would just be that you are responsible for your passport and your travel plans, and their only job is to book a flight for you. By the way, how long will you be staying in Germany? Maybe you could get a new passport before then and take both of them with you.